# Binary search for array containing negative values

Tags: data-structures, binary-search, recursive-datastructures

```
function BinarySearch(items, value) {
    var start = 0,
    stop = items.length - 1,
    mid = Math.floor((stop + start) / 2);

    while (items[mid] !== value && start < stop) {
        if (value < items[mid]) {
           stop = mid - 1;
        } else if (value > items[mid]) {
           start = mid + 1;
        }
       mid = Math.floor((stop + start) / 2);
    }
    var output = (items[mid] != value) ? -1 : mid;
    return output;
}

var arr = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, -1, 2, 3];
var key = -1;
var ans = BinarySearch(arr, key);
console.log("ans is " + ans);
```

I am trying to find - 1, using binary search but it gives incorrect result.This works fine if all array elements are positive but in case array element contains element value and we try to find negative value,it gives incorrect result.

Comment: Your array is not sorted, how do you expect binary search to work?

Comment: Thanks FrankS101..Yes array should be sorted for binary search.